# Polarity of a circuit

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, pcb, continuity

TLDR: Trying to determine polarity of pads, findings in the pics.

I’m new to electronics.

I’m trying to replace an annoying proprietary barrel connector with a direct wire to a dc power supply. I desoldered the barrel connector (excuse the bad job), but now need help determining the positive and negative terminals. I don’t have the original adapter unfortunately but have run a continuity test on the pads. The image explains what I have found. I’m thinking that the pad originally connected to the centre of the barrel is positive and as the the other pad is connected to ground or at least the surrounding unused pads (I think?) it should be negative.

Again please let me know if my thinking is incorrect and I can’t assume this.

[image]

Comment: You could show the remains of the desoldered connector. Most often the center pin is positive indeed - so far I think you noted it correctly. And you learned that measuring the Voltage beforehand would have been a good idea (-:

Comment: There's a metal piece screwed into the board on the right side of your picture. Test the continuity between the metal piece and the contacts. These metal pieces are almost always connected to negative or disconnected. It's very rare to connect them to positive.

Answer (score 0):

start with measuring resistance to mass, i.e. the metal parts around the board. If you find a terminal with about zero ohm, thats the mass connection

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the outside of th4e barrel was GND, and the center pin is +.  One connection goes to a large copper area, a probable ground plane, while the other connection goes to a much smaller copper area that has a test point.

Also, you can check continuity between the two pads and the pins of the 82 uF electrolytic.  The odds are high (but *not* 100%) that the cap - pin is GND.

There is an SO-8 device lower right.  If that is an IC and if you can find its datasheet, it might have a dedicated GND pin.

It looks like the metal tab to the right is connected to a copper area that has multiple vias to an internal plane, probably GND.